# The file name you specified is not valid or too long

Tags: windows-7

I am unable to delete files from my computer.Whenever I try to delete it, the following message appears : "THE FILE NAME YOU SPECIFIED IS NOT VALID OR TOO LONG". Is there any other method to delete that file other than booting into Linux Live Disc and mounting the Windows drive and deleting it through Linux?

Comment: shift + delete?

Comment: You can use [Delimon Win32 Explorer](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Delimon-Win32-Explorer-V40-bc957ab4) or "\\?\" notation as described in [Maximum Path Length Limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath)

Answer (score 0):

eeeh .... booting with a WinPE live USB ??? Not to get facetious here ... 
But yes that's the quickest solution. The problem is that the system just doesn't recognize the filename.

Orrrrr .... Maybe you could use the DOS filename??? Ye oilde 8.3 format, you know?

type:

```
***del Really~1.exe***
```

in a dosbox, or type

```
***cmd /k del Really~1.exe***
```

in the Runbox, if the name of your file is *"Really Long ass filename.exe"*

If that's not the name, then get the properties of that file from its context menu.

Uther than those two i got nothing.
I got a feeling you already deleted it, so we'll never know if I was brilliant or not. ;)